# Jest: function that should throw does not pass and test will fail

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, jestjs

I want to test a function `A` that calls multiple other functions inside it which can throw errors.

Here is an abstraction of my code:

```js
// file A.ts

const A = (args: any[]): boolean => {

   (() => {
      // nested function which throws
      throw new RangeError("some arg not correct")
   })()

   return true
}
```

and

```js
// file main.test.ts

test("should throw an error", () => {

   expect(A()).toThrow()

})
```

How do I test this appropriately in Jest?

The test won't succeed and jest will log the thrown error.
Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-25n1y) and here is the output of the test you can see if you run `test`:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the inner function is called immediately?  (Also known as an IIFE)

Comment: If an inner function throws and the outer does nothing with it, I am pretty sure the outer will throw too.

Comment: @PieterVanderHaegen nah the iife is meant to be representative for any inner sync function in which an error gets thrown

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried to forward the error by try/catch blocks inside function `A` so that function A is the one that is throwing (I assume that jest does not recognize the thrown error as an error of function A). I had no success with this

Comment: I can’t make guesses about code I cannot see. The code provided will be tested by jest and be found to have thrown.

Comment: I agree with @evolutionxbox . The current code throws so you can test it as in your question. Here is the TS playground example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgjAvDAFAQwE4HMIC4ZpgCeA2gLoCU+ARiCADYCmhSAfDAN4CwAULzAJQoKbTvwESA9JJhhG0RgBMYAMwCuYYFACW4GAHcAFtuCGYUQxhD6I4iecvXZjfTABKhLIwCiGKxhQAIggQAFtGAmxZEFhQP0YtQIo7AF8KYV47DEYoNQwwcww1Rl4UzJ44FHIKIA

Comment: I am so sorry. I forgot to share the error code in my description. The error is thrown indeed, but not on function A. So jest does not recognize it. I will improve my description and share a reproducible example.

Comment: @PieterVanderHaegen and evolutionxbox thanks for your help! I have revised the description of the problem and provided more details

Comment: Please note that `return true` is unreachable and will never run.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks! that was only needed to satisfy my linter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good with typescript so I have written the examples using regular JS.

It turns out you [do not need to call the `A` function to test if it throws](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror):

```js
// throw.test.js
const A = () => {
  (() => {
    // nested function which throws
    throw new RangeError("some arg not correct")
  })();
};


test("should throw an error", () => {
  expect(A).toThrow();
})
```

which outputs

```sh
> jest
 PASS  ./throw.test.js
  ✓ should throw an error (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.404s
Ran all test suites.
```

If you do want to call the function, say to pass an argument, call it within another function that's passed to the expect:

```
// throw2.test.js
const A = () => {
  (() => {
    // nested function which throws
    throw new RangeError("some arg not correct")
  })();
};


test("should throw an error", () => {
  expect(() => A('my-arg')).toThrow();
})
```

Comment: damn, should have read the docs better »Note: You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.« Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I refactored a function that was async to no longer be async and was getting this error. So, if you have an inner-async function, use this approach:

```
test("async function throws", async() => {
    await expect(() => A('my-arg')).rejects.toThrow();
})
```

You can also do some more specific checks like, what kind of error and the message, etc.

```
test("async function throws", async() => {
    await expect(() => A('my-arg')).rejects.toThrow(MyError("Specific Error Message");
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I tried different things but none of them worked for me. Your solution worked like a charm! I truly appreciate it!